# I'm unable to add new product images to new products in opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I'm trying to add new products to my website which is in opencart V2.2.0.0 and is using the Journal 2 Theme Version 2.7.1.

When I try to add new images to the gallery they are added but they're not showing on the website frontend neither are they appearing on the admin dashboard. I have tried doing resizing the image and kept the size at around 200kb and the dimensions for the images I'm adding are 1000 x 1000 pixels.

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Comment: can you provide your website details?

Comment: www.threaditionz.com

Comment: I think it's just Journal's theme problem. Try to clear cache or something like that in Journal settings

Comment: Thanks @ Alex Slipknot I cleared the cache from the Opencart Dashboard  but it didn't solve the problem! Should I clear the cache from the server too?